# "Unknown Error!" when calling pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl.SetDoc on Surface 3 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-store-apps, pdftron, pdfnet

We are having an issue with one particular device loading the PDFTron control for Windows Universal apps. The control works fine on Windows 10 on my desktop machine (Intel Xeons) and on Surface 1 (ARM running Windows 8.1). However, on our new Surface 3 (Intel Atom) running Windows 10, SetDoc fails with “Unknown Error!”:

```
Failed to set doc: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error

Unknown Error!
   at pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl.SetDoc(PDFDoc doc)
   at PDFViewCtrlDemoUniversal.ViewModels.PdfPageViewModel.SetDoc(PDFDoc doc)
The thread 0xdec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1af0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exeption at line 0 in file 
Message: Unspecified error
```

I tried both our app and PDFTron sample app (PDFViewCtrlDemoUniversal.Windows) both fail with the same error. Everything else works fine in our app on the machine, just not loading PDFs via PDFTron. The sample apps also work fine on my desktop Windows 10 install, similar with the Surface 1 ARM device on Windows 8.1.

We are running PDFTron.PDFNetUniversal.Windows version 6.5.1.31959.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 introduced pixel densities that are not recognized in the Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale enumerator from Windows 8.1.

This is why certain devices would fail, and others would not.

We have addressed this issue in our latest release (6.5.1.34018). Contact support to get the download.